# change order of events in a function

Tags: jquery, syntax, jquery-animate

I'm trying to reorder the structure of an animation. I need to remove the class `active` after the animation is complete.

I'm not sure how to queue events.

```
$('.object_pagecontent').filter(".active").removeClass("active").stop(true).animate({ marginRight : '-100%' }, 500);
```

Whats the best way to restructure?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `callback` feature of [`.animate`](https://api.jquery.com/animate/):

```
$('.object_pagecontent')
.filter(".active")
.stop(true)
.animate({
    marginRight : '-100%' 
}, 500, function(){
    $(this).removeClass("active")
});
```

Comment: ahh! Now I see. Thank you, callback! will accept in a few mins. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `callback` of [**`.animate()`**](https://api.jquery.com/animate/),

```
$('.object_pagecontent')
   .filter(".active")
   .stop(true)
   .animate({ marginRight : '-100%' }, 500,
            function() { 
              $(this).removeClass("active") 
           });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
$('.object_pagecontent')//.removeClass('active') // don't use this.
.filter(".active")
.animate({ marginRight : '-100%' }, 500,
    function() { 
    $(this).removeClass("active") 
});
```

do not remove the active class before the animation. When animation completes then use callback function as above.